# Should I remove banned contents on my database?

Tags: mysql, database, statistics, data-integrity

I'm in front of decision on `how to do with flagged data` by the users.
The banned data could be an `image`, a `wiki`, an `user` and something else need to be managed like a `message board`.

I'd like to work with `user stats` in many cases, to find users with bad behaviour, users with many activity, users with best photos and so on with all I can... I'm not sure if deleting data and use dedicated tables like `stats_table` is the best decision.

can someone suggest me something?

thanks

Comment: Suggest about what.  Can you provide a little more detail like.  what type of data how was if flagged what type of site do you run.  Are there legal/technical reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's an online community you are talking about: I wouldn't delete such data. If legal troubles come up (among users or against you) you will probably need it as evidence. If you delete such data, be sure to keep backups. This applies to any kind of community IMO.

I would delete only really, really bad stuff that could put you into jeopardy for just having it, e.g. child porn. But in such cases you would have to inform authorities straight away anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In many jurisdictions, if illegal content shows up on your website, you are legally required to report it to the authorities.  Deleting it might interfere with their investigation.  It may be that you have to remove the content from public but you must maintain it until police are satisfied. I'd consult a lawyer and find out what my responsibilities are.

Given that different jurisdictions have different definitions of illegal content, you're probably best off treating all suspect content as though it might need to be investigated by the police.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Data from a Database isnt a good idea. 
Instead try implementing something like state=0 is inaktive state=1 isactive